# Android strict mode preventing network IO

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I have been developing an android application that needs to retrieve a JSON file from dweet.io, an IOT machine-to-machine communication site. With some quick google searches I found a java wrapper for interfacing with dweet, but although it seems to work fine in theory, the Application throws some errors involving a 'Strict Mode' when it tries to reach the site. This appears to be some method of optimization standard put in place by google that prevents me from putting disk or network I/O in my Main Activity. If I can't place it in my main activity, where should I put it and how should I do that?

edit: it appears the solution involves something called 'AsyncTask', but I'm not sure how to use it or what that would entail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `MyTask` class, which extends `AsyncTask`.
Override the `doInBackground`() and maybe other functions on, need, but not required for now.

Take a look at [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)tutorial.